Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{a^2+b} \geq \frac{3}{2}$, knowing that a,b,c>0, a+b+c=3.
the problem
Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{a^2+b} \geq \frac{3}{2}$, knowing that a,b,c>0, a+b+c=3.
I applied bergstrom and got that $L-H-S \geq \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{a^3+b^3+c^3+2ab+2bc+2ca}$
Also we know that from C-B-S that $(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}=3$
I dont know what to do forward.

The inequality you obtain from the application of Cauchy-Schwarz is too weak to be of use here. To see that, take e.g. $a=\frac{3}{2},\ b=c=\frac{3}{4}$.

We have equivalently $$3=a+b+c=\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\left(\frac{a^3}{a^2+b}+\frac{ab}{a^2+b}\right)\ge\frac{3}{2}+\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\frac{ab}{a^2+b}$$ meaning that it suffices to prove $$\frac{3}{2}\ge\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\frac{ab}{a^2+b}.$$
By AM-GM it further suffices to prove $$\frac{3}{2}\ge\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\frac{ab}{2\sqrt{a^2b}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)$$ but this is easily shown by Cauchy-Schwarz, because $$9=3(a+b+c)\ge\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2$$ as desired.
